# ExecuteNonQuery returning a 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sqlconnection

I have the following code that is comparing a hash value and username to the corresponding hash value and username in a local database (**App_Users3**)

```
//-
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=DESKTOP-PGHMM6M;Initial Catalog=LocalUsers;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();                

var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Username, Hash FROM App_Users3 WHERE Hash = @Hash AND Username = @Username");
cmd.Connection = con;

// savedPasswordHash = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Hash", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = savedPasswordHash;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 400).Value = AppUsername;

if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(" Query successful.. something matched..  ");
    // change page.. load a profile? 
}
```

It doesn't throw any errors but I don't understand why the messagebox isn't showing up.

Comment: You should hash passwords with salt.

Comment: That means it didn't match anything.

Comment: Add an `else` clause to the `if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) {`, that prints another message, and you are likely to see that message getting printed

Comment: try to run SQL statement with the given value directly in SQL server and lets see what it does. certainly values in where clause does not match with data in database.

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection and SqlCommand are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. `ExecuteNonQuery` is intended for SQL which is *not* a *query* (in other words, not a `SELECT`). It is more commonly things like `INSERT`, `UPDATE ` and `DELETE`.

Comment: They should be the same values! I'm just hitting the login button after the 'create' button was used to enter the same values left in the text box

Comment: CRAP. I just realized the hashing method that I am using is asymmetrical so it will return a different value every time -_- .. I've got some work to do. Thank you, overstack community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2)  returns the rows affected by modifying data statements (insert, update, delete). You should use [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2) for such select statements, and for example return the user's ID value. If you want to return more than one value (either multiple rows or multiple columns), you should use [ExecuteReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Here is your code modified to return UserID of the matched user.

```
//-
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=DESKTOP-PGHMM6M;Initial Catalog=LocalUsers;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();                

    var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT UserId FROM App_Users3 WHERE Hash = @Hash AND Username = @Username");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    //savedPasswordHash = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Hash", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value= savedPasswordHash;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 400).Value = AppUsername;


    if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null) {
        MessageBox.Show(" Query successful..something matched..  ");
        //change page.. load a profile? 
    }
}
```

Comment: CRAP. I just realized the hashing method that I am using is assymetrical so it will return a different value every time -_- .. I've got some work to do. Thank you, overstack community